# Should there be batch operation for java Dao interface design?

Tags: java, interface, dao

Normally, we have Dao interfaces as below:

```
void add(long id);
boolean delete(long id);
```

Could we have below additional batch operation interfaces to operate in a time?

```
void add(long id);
boolean delete(long id);
void add(long[] ids); 
boolean delete(long[] ids);
```

Is this a poor design and why?

Comment: Are you talking about DAO as in "Data Access Object"?

Comment: It depends entirely on your use case. Spring Data generally does provide them (and it also provides implementations, so you don't need to write the DAOs at all).

Comment: @KevinAnderson, exactly

Comment: @chrylis
You mean Spring Data provides the batch operation as above? So can we say it's an acceptable interface design and no violation of some design principles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could we have below additional batch operation interfaces to operate in a time?

If we are talking about "Database Access Objects" then yes, the DAO hierarchies that I write certainly contain batch calls.

One of the reasons why they are powerful is that we are typically making DAO operations to underlying database storage and using a single transaction or a single database connection to make these changes can dramatically speed up operations as compared to making inserts or deletes 1 by 1.

Most ORM libraries will also disable auto-commit when inside of a transaction making inserts or deletes of a batch of entities at the same time significantly faster.

For example, my ORMLite library has:

- [Dao.create(Collection)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#create(java.util.Collection)) to create a collection of items.
- [Dao.delete(Collection)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#delete(java.util.Collection)) to delete a collection of items.